# Как конвертировать код из kotlin в java?

Tags: java, kotlin, конвертация

Как провести данную конвертацию?
Пробовал Android Studio и II - там не получается выполнить данное действие.
Вот код:

```
internal abstract class Transport {
    protected var movementType: String? = null
    protected var cargoType: String? = null
    abstract fun deliverCargo()
}
internal abstract class TransportFactory {
    abstract fun createTransport(): Transport
}
internal class ShipFactory : TransportFactory() {
    override fun createTransport(): Transport {
        return Ship()
    }
}
internal class Ship : Transport() {
    init {
        movementType = "плывет"
        cargoType = "грузовой"
    }
    override fun deliverCargo() {
        println("Грузовой корабль доставляет груз морским путем")
    }
}
internal class PlaneFactory : TransportFactory() {
    override fun createTransport(): Transport {
        return Plane()
    }
}
internal class Plane : Transport() {
    init {
        movementType = "летает"
        cargoType = "пассажирский"
    }
    override fun deliverCargo() {
        println("Пассажирский самолет доставляет пассажиров воздушным путем")
    }
}
internal class TruckFactory : TransportFactory() {
    override fun createTransport(): Transport {
        return Truck()
    }
}
internal class Truck : Transport() {
    init {
        movementType = "едет"
        cargoType = "грузовой"
    }

    override fun deliverCargo() {
        println("Грузовая машина доставляет грузы по дороге")
    }
}
object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val shipFactory: TransportFactory = ShipFactory()

        val ship = shipFactory.createTransport()

        ship.deliverCargo()

        val planeFactory: TransportFactory = PlaneFactory()

        val plane = planeFactory.createTransport()

        plane.deliverCargo()

        val truckFactory: TransportFactory = TruckFactory()

        val truck = truckFactory.createTransport()

        truck.deliverCargo()
    }
}
```

Comment: Что имеется в виду под конвертацией?  По идее вы можете скомпилировать код на Котлине и использовать его из Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможный вариант "буквальной" конвертации:

```java
abstract class Transport {
    protected String movementType = null;
    protected String cargoType = null;
    public abstract void deliverCargo();
}
abstract class TransportFactory {
    public abstract Transport createTransport();
}
class ShipFactory extends TransportFactory {
    @Override public Transport createTransport() {
        return new Ship();
    }
}
class Ship extends Transport {
    {
        movementType = "плывет";
        cargoType = "грузовой";
    }
    @Override public void deliverCargo() {
        System.out.println("Грузовой корабль доставляет груз морским путем");
    }
}
class PlaneFactory extends TransportFactory {
    @Override public Transport createTransport() {
        return new Plane();
    }
}
class Plane extends Transport {
    {
        movementType = "летает";
        cargoType = "пассажирский";
    }
    @Override public void deliverCargo() {
        System.out.println("Пассажирский самолет доставляет пассажиров воздушным путем");
    }
}
class TruckFactory extends TransportFactory {
    @Override public Transport createTransport() {
        return new Truck();
    }
}
class Truck extends Transport {
    {
        movementType = "едет";
        cargoType = "грузовой";
    }

    @Override public void deliverCargo() {
        System.out.println("Грузовая машина доставляет грузы по дороге");
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        var shipFactory = new ShipFactory();

        var ship = shipFactory.createTransport();

        ship.deliverCargo();

        var planeFactory = new PlaneFactory();

        var plane = planeFactory.createTransport();

        plane.deliverCargo();

        var truckFactory = new TruckFactory();

        var truck = truckFactory.createTransport();

        truck.deliverCargo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Всё работает.